# Layout the Windows Picker in MAUI.NET through AppendToMapping

Tags: combobox, customization, maui, picker, winui-3

I must to change the look of standard picker control. For now only in case of Windows. So I did AppendToMapping and successfully changed the background color.

the code in MauiProgram.cs:

```
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.ElementMapper.AppendToMapping("Classic", (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is myPicker)
            {
                EntryMapper.Map(handler, view);
            }
        });
```

and my new control definition:

```
public class myPicker : Picker
{
    public static BindableProperty PopupBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PopupBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(iCPicker), Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    public Color PopupBackgroundColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(PopupBackgroundColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(PopupBackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }
}
```

XAML declaration:

```
<uiUtilities:myPicker PopupBackgroundColor="Blue"/>
```

all is fine to setup - for a test - background color of the combobox

```
    public static class EntryMapper
    {
        public static void Map(IElementHandler handler, IElement view)
        {
            if(view is myPicker)
            {
                var casted = (PickerHandler)handler;
                var view2 = (myPicker)view;
                view2.BackgroundColor = view2.PopupBackgroundColor; // this works for test
                // but actually want to change the dropdown of this combobox
            }
        }
    }
```

but my aim is to modify this drop-down list which appears when you click in picker / combobox. I wan to set its background color, corner radius, shadow, border, perhaps move it slightly and maybe customize more. And if possible disable this Window's theme color for a currently selected item.

I was looked into a structure of combobox in WinUI 3.0 as this is underlying control for Windows, but anyway I can't find it through a view2 object. I was trying to dig to VisualTree etc.

**How to access this dropdown element?**

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to modify dropdown element by Handlers, but failed like yours.

> but my aim is to modify this drop-down list which appears when you click in picker / combobox. I wan to set its background color, corner radius, shadow, border, perhaps move it slightly and maybe customize more. And if possible disable this Window's theme color for a currently selected item.

You can refer to the source code of [windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/winui3/release/1.4-stable/controls/dev/ComboBox/ComboBox_themeresources.xaml).

Take the background and border thickness of the drop-down box as an example, add some code in the **Project/Platforms/Windows/App.xaml** file:

```xml
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
              x:Class="MauiApp1.WinUI.App"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
              xmlns:local="using:MauiApp1.WinUI">

    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDropDownBackground" Color="#48b7d5" />
        <Thickness x:Key="ComboBoxDropdownBorderThickness">5</Thickness>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

And this is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36CPl.jpg).